# How to use nested Touchables with react native gesture handler

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm trying to change all my Touchables to react native gesture handler, but when I have some nested Touchables it just doesn't work the same way, this an example:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => setMenuVisible(false)}
     <View style={styles.rightContentTop}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleUsernameTap}>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{username}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When I use the Touchables from react native there is no problem, but when I change them to the ones from react native gesture handler both are getting call when I click on the nested one, what am I missing?

Edit:

The problem seems to be happening only in Android.

Comment: which mean that you want to both `setMenuVisible(false)` and `handleUsernameTap` to be called when u press the top buttons, right ?

Comment: I want that only the nested one get call but when I click both of the them are called

Comment: Hi Patricio, did you find a solution? I'm experiencing this right now

Comment: Hi, no I haven't found any solution for this problem using react native gesture handler. There is currently an issue open on its Github repository.